# Disabling drag and drop on x window manager

Tags: linux, bash, x11, kiosk, kiosk-mode

I am setting up a kiosk to be available for people to download files from a local web server. my base operating system is ubuntu server. On top of that is Sanickiosk which I used to create a kiosk environment, then I switched their choice of browser for firefox with the mKiosk extension.

The problem is that there is a vulnerability in that a file can be dragged from the dowload location chooser into firefox and then opened.

I tried searching for how to disable the drag and drop function in the x window manager and did not find any clues.

I am wondering if I can add something to the bash script that disables right click and starts the browser.

**Edit:** wondering if there is a way to instantly "release" the mouse click on mouse click thereby preventing drag and drop?

Any help would be appreciated. thanks.

Comment: This function doesn't have much to do with the window manager. You can disable the right click by remapping mouse buttons. Google `x11 remap mouse buttons`. You need to make sure *no other button/key combination* does anything unwanted.

Comment: my main concern is drag and drop from download "file explorer" where they can find something on their flash drive, and open it on the kiosk via drag and drop to firefox.

Comment: Drag n drop doesn't even use the right click. There's nothing you can do here on the X11 side. Firefox handles it all itself. Ask mKiosk developers how to disable drag-n-drop. Even if you can "instantly" force a release event, it's unreliable and dangerous. You don't know how really instant is your "instantly". You can also try to mount the user's drive with dmask=0777 and fmask=0222.